# ASP.Net C# - Multiple UpdateProgress controls on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

I'm trying to implement UpdatePanels and UpdateProgress controls.  I have two UpdatePanels that contain two different DropDownLists (ddlQuestion5IDs and ddlQuestion6IDs).

When I change the selected index of ddlQuestion6IDs, the UpdateProgress loads for both UpdatePanels/DropDownLists.  Is this how they normally behave and is there a way of only displaying the corresponding UpdateProgress for each UpdatePanel?

```
        <p>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Question 5:" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuestion5IDs" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlQuestion5IDs_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true">
                        <ProgressTemplate>
                            <img src="images/loader.gif" height="20" />
                        </ProgressTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="Question type:" Font-Italic="true"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion5Type" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <br /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server" Text="Question:" Font-Italic="true"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion5" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlQuestion5IDs" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Question 6:" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuestion6IDs" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlQuestion6IDs_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true">
                        <ProgressTemplate>
                            <img src="images/loader.gif" height="20" />
                        </ProgressTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" Text="Question type:" Font-Italic="true"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion6Type" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <br /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label24" runat="server" Text="Question:" Font-Italic="true"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion6" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlQuestion6IDs" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a  AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelID" property to UpdateProgress